# How to pick the nth occurance in web source code

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to locate the 52 Week Price Range via Yahoo Finance for a list of tickers.

URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL

I have looked online and youtube and used a lot of guidance from there. However, when I run the code it picks the first instance of the array when in fact I need the 6th. Because the page appears to be made up of a lot of other tickers too, the one I need is not the first, according to the string I'm searching for - "fiftyTwoWeekRange".

Is there a way I can specify the search to pick up not the first but the 'nth' occurrence? Thanks for any help. The code I am using I found on YouTube which was very helpful but I'm hoping you guys can help out with this tweak.

```
Sub qTest_3()

    Call clear_data

    Dim myrng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim row_count As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Main2")

    col_count = 2
    row_count = 2

    'Find last row
    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'set ticker range
    Set myrng = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1))

    'llop through tickers
    For Each ticker In myrng

        'Send web request
        Dim URL2 As String: URL2 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker & "?p=" & ticker & ""
        Dim Http2 As New WinHttpRequest

        Http2.Open "GET", URL2, False
        Http2.Send

        Dim s As String
        'Get source code of site
        s = Http2.ResponseText

        Dim metrics As Variant
        '**** Metric fields here
        metrics = Array("fiftyTwoWeekRange")


        'Split string here
        For Each element In metrics

            firstTerm = Chr(34) & element & Chr(34) & ":{" & Chr(34) & "raw" & Chr(34) & ":"
            secondTerm = "," & Chr(34) & "fmt" & Chr(34)

            nextPosition = 1

            On Error GoTo err_hdl

            Do Until nextPosition = 0
                startPos = InStr(nextPosition, s, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
                stopPos = InStr(startPos, s, secondTerm, vbTextCompare)
                split_string = Mid$(s, startPos + Len(firstTerm), stopPos - startPos - Len(secondTerm))
                nextPosition = InStr(stopPos, s, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)

                Exit Do
            Loop

            On Error GoTo 0

            Dim arr() As String
            arr = Split(split_string, ",")
            metric = arr(0)

            'Output to sheet
            ws.Range(Cells(row_count, col_count), Cells(row_count, col_count)).Value = metric
            col_count = col_count + 1

getData:

        Next element

        Dim symbol As String
        symbol = ticker

        col_count = 2
        row_count = row_count + 1

    Next ticker

    MsgBox ("Done")

    Exit Sub

err_hdl:
    ws.Range(Cells(row_count, col_count), Cells(row_count, col_count)).Value = "N/A"
    Resume getData

End Sub
Sub clear_data()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Main2")
    Dim lastrow, lastcol As Long
    Dim myrng As Range

    With ws
     lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    lastcol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set myrng = ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

    myrng.Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an odd method for parsing HTML in my opinion and inefficient.

**Good way:**

If you are after the range you can use `querySelector` method of `HTMLDocument` if you store the response in an `HTMLDocument` variable. I would look into CSS selectors, for example, as a better way to get the data you are interested in.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Debug.Print html.querySelector("[data-test=FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value]").innertext
End Sub
```

This uses a CSS selector to target the element by its attribute. The `[]` means attribute selector. It matches on an element with attribute `data-test` whose value is `FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value`

---

**Element in question:**

[image: test]

---

**Less desirable way:**

A less desirable method would be to use Split to cut out what you are after e.g.

```
Debug.Print Split(Split(Split(Http2.ResponseText, "data-test=""FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value""")(1), "<")(0), ">")(1)
```

---

A version that may fit easier with your code is as follows (normally I would put the range into an array and loop that as quicker but this is closer to yours):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, http As Object, ticker As Range
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set http = CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

    Dim lastRow As Long, myrng As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main2")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set myrng = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

        For Each ticker In myrng
            If Not IsEmpty(ticker) Then
                With http
                    .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ticker.Value & "?p=" & ticker.Value, False
                    .send
                    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                End With
                On Error Resume Next
                ticker.Offset(, 1) = html.querySelector("[data-test=FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value]").innertext
               'ticker.Offset(, 1) = Split(Split(Split(http.ResponseText, "data-test=""FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value""")(1), "<")(0), ">")(1)  ''<<Or this version 
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a nice way to go.

Comment: Hi there. Firstly, thanks for taking the time out to look at my query. I have to say I'm fairly new to VBA and my effort is about as far as I've got. Sorry to say this but I am way off understanding your terms etc. Maybe I need to do a bit more learning and research so I can understand when help is offered. I will take a closer look and try to understand more what you have suggested. I was rather hoping there was a small addition/amendment to my code that would get what I was after. Thanks again.

Comment: Hiya, I am more than happy to help you understand the top version. I have given you a version you can use with your code as is at the bottom. See the bit under _Less desirable way:_ There are lots of courses that teach what I consider, and that is only my opinion, inefficient ways of parsing HTML. I myself have just completed a python course that did the very same thing.

Comment: That's very helpful. Where in my original code would I insert the additional line? I have a list of ~2500 tickers which I need to run the code against. Its the 6th instance in the source code, whereas mine is bringing up the 1st instance.

Comment: This  Split(Split(Split(Http2.ResponseText, "data-test=""FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE-value""")(1), "<")(0), ">")(1) returns the value you want. Use it as you need.

Comment: I'd just like to thank you for your efforts here, but at this time if my life depended on it I wouldn't know where to put that piece of code within the code I have already got. I'd love to learn more about your 'Good Way', and will endeavor to do so, when I will come back and laugh at myself for being so naïve. Sorry if I have frustrated you somewhat!

Comment: OK. I have an excel sheet with all the tickers in column A. The results from my code are placed in column B, all the way down (~2500 rows) - but are incorrect. The phrase "fiftyTwoWeekRange" is found in the source code numerous times, but my code picks up the first instance, which isn't for Apple (AAPL). When I run the code I would like the price range in column B to be for the stock ticker in column A - but as it is the 6th instance of "fiftyTwoWeekRange" my code never picks it up? Your piece of code may well help but i'm at a loss where to use it?

Comment: I have added a version that more closely resembles your code. If you see where I have written _Element in question:_, that is the HTML for the element you want. It has something called an [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) which is what I am using to target the element.

Comment: Yes, that is the value I was looking for. When I use your code in a new workbook, it is highlighting an error 'As HTMLDocument'. Am I missing something very obvious? This is great discussion for me btw!

Comment: It means you probably haven't added a reference to the library. In the VBE go to Tools > References and scroll down to Microsoft HTML Object Library then tick the box.

Comment: Woah, what kind of sorcery is that? I'm amazed how much some people know about stuff. That really has impressed me - thanks for your time and your perseverance with this simpleton. Cheers

Comment: Don't do yourself an injustice. SO is here so we learn from each other. Being open to that experience is the key thing.

Comment: One last thing if I may. If I want to change the "fiftyTwoWeekRange" to say "regularMarketPreviousClose" - what would I need to change? It is simply a case of changing the reference FIFTY_TWO_WK_RANGE? :)

Comment: It's a great technique isn't it?

Comment: Good morning. I have a further (last) query if I may. Your solution is working great, and I've created a number of sheets where I can gather different stock info. Was wondering if there was a way to incorporate a number of queries in to the same VBA code. It would just serve me easier if I can click one button and have a number of columns populated instead of just one? Any help as before very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes but can you post a new question explaining exactly what is needed? For example, do you have a list of URLs to loop extracting the same info from each? Different info? What is the layout for how you are writing the information, why are several sheets involved etc...... If you post explaining this and where you are stuck with the current code and put a link here I will definitely have a look. It is possible you want a custom class to hold the XMLHTTP object with method/s for getting the info required and an array to hold the various links that you can loop.